# Visual Studio third party plugin creation

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, salesforce

So as I sit here pondering this idea that I have, I am curious on where to even start if this is possible.  I work for Salesforce (specifically supporting the Marketing Cloud application - a web app).  We have several publicly available API's (SOAP and REST) for third party integrations to take place and impact data within the Marketing Cloud environment.  So, to keep this on a simple level and not go into detail around the Marketing Cloud, is it possible to somehow write a sort of plug-in for Visual Studio that will, upon certain actions in Visual Studio, make API calls to a third party (in this case, I'm talking about Salesforce Marketing Cloud).  My end goal is for Visual Studio to be able to initiate a custom action (API call to a third party) whenever a certain action happens from within Visual Studio.  I hope this makes sense!  Where would I start with this if this is possible?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is for VS or VS Code, will assume VS Code as it is compatible with both Windows and Mac.

What you're asking for should theoretically be possible because of the structure of the Electron app which VS Code is built on. Also it useses NodeJS.

I'm a Mac user, but when I used VS Code, I found this tutorial helpful for getting started:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qV0e7LSQOIE

Also the docs are pretty helpful too:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview

And there is this little boilerplate I found online too:

https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-plugin-boilerplate